# How can a variadic function be used by reflect.MakeFunc

Tags: go

The following is an excerpt from the MakeFunc Example in the reflection
documentation.  I understand how it works with as it is shown.

```
// Make and call a swap function for ints.
var intSwap func(int, int) (int, int)
makeSwap(&intSwap)
fmt.Println(intSwap(0, 1))
```

WHAT I DON'T UNDERSTAND is how in the heck could it be used with a 
variadic input.

```
var intswap func(...int) (...int)   // Got to be wrong
var intswap func(...int) (int, int) // Will not work even with 2 inputs
```

Can someone give an example of MakeFunc using a variadic input??

Can not find an example anywhere on the net!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A variadic argument is just represented as a slice, so in your example the swap function arguments would be a single slice of Values, instead of multiple Values. You can access the slice values via the `Value.Index` method:  https://play.golang.org/p/2b22FV_5v8

```
swap := func(in []reflect.Value) []reflect.Value {
    return []reflect.Value{in[0].Index(1), in[0].Index(0)}
}

makeSwap := func(fptr interface{}) {
    fn := reflect.ValueOf(fptr).Elem()
    v := reflect.MakeFunc(fn.Type(), swap)
    fn.Set(v)
}

var intSwap func(...int) (int, int)
makeSwap(&intSwap)
fmt.Println(intSwap(0, 1))
```